# Listen for ng-dirty in multiple forms

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm building a app using AngularJs

In one of my template partials I use "ng-repeat" to spawn multiple forms:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4 usbDevices">
  <li ng-repeat="usbDevice in usbDevices">
    <div class="block">
      <form name="form{{usbDevice.id}}">
        <!-- input fields -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I make that when any one of this forms shows up "ng-dirty" a "Save" button shows in the bottom? Do I need a watcher?

```
<a href="#" class="button expanded">Save</a>
```

Comment: `ng-dirty` just sounds wrong for some reason.

Comment: I want that the "Save" button shows up as soon as the user makes any change to any of the fields. When the user makes some modification, the class "ng-dirty" is added to the form. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it all in [`ng-form`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) , something like:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-form="MainForm">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4 usbDevices" >
      <li ng-repeat="usbDevice in usbDevices">
        <div class="block">
          <form name="form{{usbDevice.id}}">
            <input required ng-model="usbDevice.description" >
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-show="MainForm.$valid">Save</button>
  </body>
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0CyyoqVHzs4ZV1F6uG4